# datatables fnDeleteRow does not update results per page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm working with datatables. There is an event that deletes a row. Data deletion occurs via ajax, and client deletion with fnDeleteRow.

It works right, the row is removed from the table, but occurs this: I have defined 4 results per page, so, if I remove one of them, the page that contained it, now has only 3 results, and the rest have 4. It should be re-paginated so the only page with less than 4 results were the last, if the total is not a multiple of 4.

Also, the number of results info is incorrect: if originally I had 6 results and I delete noe of them, the info should "showing 1 to 4 of 5 rows", but it still says "showing 1 to 4 of 6 rows". And the page only has 3 rows.

Anybody can help me with this? I hope I have been clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Give [`fnStandingRedraw()`](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnStandingRedraw) a try. This will redraw the table and keep your pagination in place.